# Simple migration from S3 to Google Cloud Storage without changing boto code

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, boto

In: 
https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#migration-simple

It says that simple migration just needs the Google developer key and secret to replace the AWS key and secret.

However, in code that uses boto, how can you change the endpoint to use the Google Storage endpoint instead of the AWS endpoint?

I can see that you can use `boto.gs.GSConnection` instead of `boto.s3.S3Connection`, but I'd like to avoid changing code.

Comment: You might still have to change a small amount of code. Can you post some of your S3 code?

Comment: I made the change similar to the answer below. I was hoping it was possible to switch through pure configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't need to be aware of the different connection type, but you do need to call a different method to make your connection.  My code worked with just two changes:

1. I changed

   ```
   my_connection = boto.connect_s3()
   ```

   to

   ```
   my_connection = boto.connect_gs(goog_dev_key, goog_dev_secret)
   ```
2. I changed my bucket naming connection to avoid embedded periods, which are unacceptable on GS.

All other code remained the same.